# Firebase InstanceId unresolved identifier swift4

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have recently updated My SWIFT applications pod file, And because of that firebase version is now updated to a 5.2.
Which now gives me following error while getting a device instance id.

```
let tokenId = InstanceID.instanceID().token()
```

error: **Use of unresolved identifier 'InstanceID'**

Previously this code was working fine and I was getting Application's Instance Id.

Following is content of my pod file.

```
   # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '11.2'

target 'FirebaseChat' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for FirebaseChat

pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'UnderLineTextField', '~> 2.0'
pod 'Alamofire'
pod 'TCPickerView'
pod 'Toast-Swift', '~> 3.0.1'
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
end
```

Any suggestions will be helpful.
Thank You.

Comment: solved the problem after adding pod 'FirebaseInstanceID' into my pod file. but previously i don't had it in my pod file then how it was working?

Comment: Firebase 5.x removed some unnecessary implicit dependencies

Answer (score 18):

You should import FirebaseInstanceID

```
  import FirebaseInstanceID
```

Comment: If you are facing this issue in 2020, read @NikileshBalaji answer for the right solution

Answer (score 6):

Firebase made changes for token in FirebaseInstanceID update so now ***they changed syntaxes to get token***

Try this

```
InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID(handler: { (result, error) in
    if let error = error{
        print("Error fetching remote instange ID(Token): \(error)")
    }else if let result = result{
        print("Remote instance ID token: \(result.token)")

    }
})
```

and import

```
import FirebaseInstanceID
```

Comment: make sure to add: import FirebaseInstanceID. I got it from @Karthikeyan's answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/58641464/4833705

Answer (score 6):

Firebase have not yet updated their doc but then updated their api to get the Instance id

`import FirebaseInstallations`

and then

```
Installations.installations().authToken { (installationsAuthTokenResult, error) in
    if let authError = error {
            print(authError.localizedDescription)
    } else {
            print(installationsAuthTokenResult?.authToken.description)
    }
}
```

for more information please check this [link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/pull/5561/files) by Firebase team.

Comment: "import FirebaseInstallations" doesn't resolve for latest version - No such module 'FirebaseInstallations'

Answer (score 1):

Syntax changed in latest update

```
if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
        print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
    }
```

Comment: Great! It worked for me!
Just one fix: FIRInstanceID should be replaced with InstanceID