# Firebase InstanceID.instanceID().token() method is deprecated

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, token

I am working with swift and firebase. Previously I was using following method to get firebase token which then I was using  to store into database to send notifications.

```
InstanceID.instanceID().token()
```

Now this method is showing as deprecated since i have updated my firebase.

```
'token()' is deprecated: Use instanceIDWithHandler: instead.
```

I don't know how to use `instanceIDWithHandler` i have tried following but don't know how to get token.

```
func instanceID(handler: @escaping InstanceIDResultHandler){

    }
```

Please help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you asking about [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#fetching-the-current-registration-token)?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

[*Fetching the current registration token*](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client)

> Registration tokens are delivered via the method `messaging:didReceiveRegistrationToken:`. This method is called generally once per app start with an FCM token. When this method is called, it is the ideal time to:

> - If the registration token is new, send it to your application server.

- Subscribe the registration token to topics. This is required only for new subscriptions or for situations where the user has re-installed the app.

> You can retrieve the token directly using **`instanceIDWithHandler:`**. This callback provides an **`InstanceIDResult`**, which contains the token. A non null error is provided if the InstanceID retrieval failed in any way.

You should import FirebaseInstanceID

```
  import FirebaseInstanceID
```

**objective C**

on your getTokenMethod

```
[[FIRInstanceID instanceID] instanceIDWithHandler:^(FIRInstanceIDResult * _Nullable result,
                                                NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error fetching remote instance ID: %@", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Remote instance ID token: %@", result.token);
    }
}];
```

**Swift**

```
InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { result, error in
    if let error = error {
        print("Error fetching remote instange ID: \(error)")
    } else if let result = result {
        print("Remote instance ID token: \(result.token)")
    }
}
```

**Update**

`InstanceID` is now deprecated. Try

```
Messaging.messaging().token { token, error in
   // Check for error. Otherwise do what you will with token here
}
```

Comment: this solution is working perfect thank you Sir. I want to know where did you get this answer or where i can learn such things. When I read firebase documentation this is what i found [link](https://ibb.co/d4ahqT) which was not useful at all or I was unable to understand it.

Comment: @user9496018 the docs with this information are here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/first-message

Comment: Some of our users are having problem with this new solution, the lambda never returns the result.

Comment: same as @PedroPauloAmorim :(

Comment: same problem, the lambda never return the result!

Comment: the **result** will be of type **InstanceIDResult**. To the Strings from it use **let newToken = result.token** and **let instanceId = result.instanceID**

Comment: lambda hangs for me when i configure firebase using SEGFirebaseIntegrationFactory instead of FirebaseApp.configure()

Comment: make sure to add: import FirebaseInstanceID  https://stackoverflow.com/a/58641464/4833705

Comment: As instanceId is deprecated, now you can use 

Messaging.messaging().token { token, error in
   // Check for error. Otherwise do what you will with token here
}

Answer (score 57):

`InstanceID` is now deprecated. Try

```
Messaging.messaging().token { token, error in
   // Check for error. Otherwise do what you will with token here
}
```

See [Documentation on Fetching the current registration token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#fetching-the-current-registration-token)

Answer (score 9):

Here the solution

The problem is that FirebaseInstanceID has recently become deprecated

Old

`InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID {result, _ in`

New

`Messaging.messaging().token { (token, _) in`

You can replace it like above, it working

Check below link

https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/how-to-solve-capacitor-error-no-such-module-firebaseinstanceid-9c142933b589

Answer (score 0):

**Update for Objective-C**

```
[[FIRMessaging messaging] tokenWithCompletion:^(NSString * _Nullable token, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error fetching remote instance ID: %@", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Remote instance ID token: %@", token);
    }
}];
```