# Ways to retrieve FCM Token with Firebase?

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, swift4

I am using `Firebase` trying to get the FCM Token so I can test Push notifications on an actual device. I get the `APNS` token fine, set it with

```
Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken,
```

but when I try to use `Messaging.messaging().fcmToken` to get the FCM token, it returns nil, as well as

```
InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, error)  in } //returning nil.
```

However, when I use  `Messaging.messaging().retrieveFCMToken` or `InstanceID.instanceID().getID` I get results, yet I see no one advocating for the use of these functions to get the FCM token. Are these functions correct ways to get the FCM token?

Comment: Also, didReceiveRegistrationToken is not firing off for some reason either, even though all my delegates are setup correctly and I am getting the apns token correctly

Comment: Have you assigned delegate ?

Comment: Yes Messaging.messaging().delegate = self is set after FirebaseApp.configure(), and UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self is set properly as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one it's work for me **(swift 4 Code)**

**Request for permission**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    self.setupFirebase(applicatin: application)
}
```

**Setup Firebase** `registerUserNotificationSettings`

```
func setupFirebase(applicatin:UIApplication)
{
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let authOptions : UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge , .sound]

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
        options: authOptions,
        completionHandler: {_,_ in })
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
        // FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self
    } else {

        let notificationtype :UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.alert,UIUserNotificationType.badge,UIUserNotificationType.sound]
        let notificationsettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: notificationtype, categories: nil)

        applicatin.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationsettings)
    }
    applicatin.registerForRemoteNotifications()
}
```

**Getting device token**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

    guard InstanceID.instanceID().token() != nil
        else {
            return
    }

    if let refreshedToken = InstanceID.instanceID().token()
    {
        print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
    }
}
```

**In case of error**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("Filed to register : \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Comment: *InstanceID.instanceID().token()*  has depricated, plz read this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50945015/firebase-instanceid-instanceid-token-method-is-deprecated/50945350#50945350