# FirebaseInstallations will not work correctly with current version of Firebase Instance ID. Please update your Firebase Instance ID version

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm using Xcode 12.4 and I upgraded cocoapods to `1.10.1` and updated my all of my Firebase pods. Afterwards when I ran the project I kept getting an `InstanceID()` error. I then googled it and it turns out FirebaseInstanceID [is deprecate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId)d and I had to use `Firebase/Installations`:

```
// add this to the podfile
pod 'Firebase/Installations'

$ pod install
```

After the Firebase/Installations update I kept getting the error:

> FirebaseInstallations will not work correctly with current version of
> Firebase Instance ID. Please update your Firebase Instance ID version.

It didn't make any sense because FirebaseInstanceID is deprecated so how could I update it. I followed this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/5213) which was of no help.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I sent a PR to improve the error message in https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/pull/8279

Answer (score 1):

I spent a couple of hours on this. I don't undestand why they have the error that says **Please update your Firebase Instance ID version**. To fix this issue I had to remove FirebaseInstanceID from my podfile

```
// add a # sign in front of FirebaseInstanceID inside your podfile
#pod 'FirebaseInstanceID'

// then run
$ pod install
```

Inside AppDelegate I had to remove the **import FirebaseInstanceID** library

```
import FirebaseInstanceID // delete this
```

To get the token I followed this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64248707/4833705:

Replace this deprecated method:

```
InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, error) in { }
```

With this:

```
Messaging.messaging().token { (token, error) in { }
```

**Sidenote** If you get errors you might have to delete and reinstall all of your pods but this shouldn't be necessary.

Make sure you make a copy of the Podfile before doing these steps.

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate

$ sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate cocoapods-clean

$ rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

$ pod deintegrate

$ pod clean

$ rm Podfile

$ pod cache clean --all

$ pod init
```

Open the new Podfile then add everything from the copy